How to process each video frame when using Exoplayer play a RTSP stream?
Here is a similar question, I am using exoplayer to pull and decode a RTSP stream, it can display the video now, but I want apply a deep learning model to detect something appeared on each frame.
From the answer of andrewlewis, I think using a ImageReader is the easiest solution, but I am new to android development and couldn't find any examples trying my best. I hope someone can help me, and other solution to this problem can also be accepted.
